# Passing integer expl3 variables to a Lua function (via \lua_new:e)?

Tags: errors, luatex, lua, variable, function

Given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N\g_test_myint_int
\int_set:Nn\g_test_myint_int{2}

\cs_set:Npn\__test_dostuff: {
  \lua_now:e{tex.sprint(1)} % Works just fine.
  \lua_now:e{tex.sprint(\g_test_myint_int)} % Does not work.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\__test_dostuff:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

I get an the following error.

```
\directlua]:1: unexpected symbol near '\'.
\lua_now:e #1->\__lua_now:n {#1}

l.17 \__test_dostuff:
```

I know with strings I can use `\luaescapestring{}` to properly escape and send things off to my Lua functions.  Is there a way to pass integer variables to Lua functions?  While I can call `tonumber(int)` inside my Lua function and get what I need, I feel like there's something simple I'm missing.

Additionally, is there a similar method for passing booleans directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int` are not expandable, you need to expand the value with `\int_use:N`

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N\g_test_myint_int
\int_set:Nn\g_test_myint_int{2}

\cs_set:Npn\__test_dostuff: {
  \lua_now:e{tex.sprint(1)} % Works just fine.
  \lua_now:e{tex.sprint(\int_use:N\g_test_myint_int)} % Does not work.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\__test_dostuff:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should use  a local variable or a global assignment in `\int_set:Nn\g_test_myint_int{2}`

Comment: I would probably use `\lua_now:e{tex.sprint(tex.count["g_test_myint_int"])}`, things are easier if there are less backslashes.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I was missing.  And an interesting tip about calling `tex.count()` as well.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your method would fail if instead of a variable you want to pass a constant.